# How do I target the second character with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery to target hyphens in word combinations in order to apply special styling.

The words are part of a filtering system and appear like this:

```
<ul id="filters" >
<li class="current"><a href="#all">All-Work</a>
<ul>
<li><a class="filterName" href="#Branding-and-Logo">Branding-and-Logo</a></li>
<li><a class="filterName" href="#Content-Management">Content-Management</a></li>
<li><a class="filterName" href="#Infographics">Infographics</a></li>
<li><a class="filterName" href="#Media-Integration">Media-Integration</a></li>
<li><a class="filterName" href="#Mobile-sites">Mobile-sites</a></li>
<li><a class="filterName" href="#Photography">Photography</a></li>
<li><a class="filterName" href="#Print">Print</a></li>
<li><a class="filterName" href="#Video">Video</a></li>
<li><a class="filterName" href="#Websites">Websites</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

I am using the following jQuery to target the hyphen between words:

```
$('a:contains("-")').html(function () {
return $(this).text().replace('-', '<span class="hideme">-</span>')
});
```

This works on all instances except the first item in the list: Branding-and-Logo, where the second hyphen is not modified. You can see how the second hyphen still shows in the lists [here](http://rouviere.net/our-work/).

What else needs to be done to target the second hyphen as well as the first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.replace` only replace the first instance passed in argument. You could call replace until there is no more hyphen, use [dave's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24660165/2324107) (which is good) or use regExp global flag like that :

```
return $(this).text().replace(/-/g, '<span class="hideme">-</span>');
```

Answer (score 2):

When I need to replace all instances of a string I usually use `split` and `join`

```
return $(this).text().split('-').join('<span class="hideme">-</span>')
```

Answer (score 1):

Javascript replace function only replaces the first occurrence of the pattern. To replace all you must use a regular expression such as:

```
$('a:contains("-")').html(function () {
    return $(this).text().replace(/-/g, '<span class="hideme">-</span>')
});
```